# If an attribute has ranges as its possible values, is that attribute a numerical attribute or a categorical (ordinal categorical) attribute

Tags: categorical-data, ratio

For example if I ask for someone's age, but instead of them being able to enter any natural number their responses are cropped and saved into bins such as "1-10" and "11-20" etc. Is this a numerical or a categorical attribute?

Asking as I'm confused whether its categorical nature overrides the fact that it is still sort of ratio-scaled.

Comment: Numerical variable is binned to make ordinal categorical variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ask not what an attribute is--ask what sort of analysis makes sense :-).

Often it is helpful to think in terms of "This analysis treated attribute A as {ratio | interval | ordinal | categorical}."

For some attributes, there might be only one plausible answer.

For other attributes, like broad age bins, there might be two or more answers that could yield useful results.  Then you need to be able to explain why it might make sense to do the analysis in a particular way, and also be aware of the potential limitations or shortcomings of doing it that way.

For some helpful [definitions](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/what-is-the-difference-between-categorical-ordinal-and-interval-variables/).  Other search results are available.